# How to show json objects(with diffrent data fileds) in a datatable?

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, dynamic, datatable

İ want to show json objects in a datatable. (C#.MVC) Due fact that json object have mostly different fileds according machines data they belong. For each json object i dont want to write a seperate class. How can i handle this json objects dynamically and show datatable in a single class?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/), an open source library, you can do it as follows

```
string json = @"{
    ""header"": ""myheader"",
    ""transaction"": {
    ""date"": ""2019-09-24"",
    ""items"": [
        {
        ""number"": ""123"",
        ""unit"": ""EA"",
        ""qty"": 6
        },
        {
        ""number"": ""456"",
        ""unit"": ""CS"",
        ""qty"": 4
        }
    ]
    }
}";

using (var r = ChoJSONReader.LoadText(json))
{
    var dt = r.Select(f => f.Flatten()).AsDataTable();
    Console.WriteLine(dt.DumpAsJson());
}
```

**Output**:

```
[
  {
    "header": "myheader",
    "transaction_date": "2019-09-24",
    "transaction_items_0_number": "123",
    "transaction_items_0_unit": "EA",
    "transaction_items_0_qty": 6,
    "transaction_items_1_number": "456",
    "transaction_items_1_unit": "CS",
    "transaction_items_1_qty": 4
  }
]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Any idea how to show on datable?

Comment: the call `var dt = r.Select(f => f.Flatten()).AsDataTable();` returns datatable.